# New to physics and need some help with understanding acceleration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, acceleration

1. The free fall acceleration of an object under earth's gravity is directed toward?
2. When the same amount of force is applied to two different masses, the smaller mass will be accelerated ***_*___** than the larger?

Comment: Why don't you try explaining why you are struggling with this?

Comment: Hi rb1234, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This is a site for conceptual questions about physics, not general homework help. If you can edit your question to ask about the specific physics concept that is giving you trouble, I'll be happy to reopen it. See our [FAQ#questions] and [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for more information.

Comment: Okay. But why delete the answer...? I mean the "damage" has been done, so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

1) The *center* of the earth. As Wouter pointed out this is really supposed to be the center of mass of the Earth which differs only slightly from the center.*

2) The smaller mass will be accelerated more. This follows from $F=m a$. At constant $F$, smaller $m$ implies larger $a$.

*Since the Earth is not a perfect sphere it does not have a center as such. But the point is moot anyway.

Comment: The acceleration will actually be directed toward the *center of mass* of the earth, which is not located exactly at the center of the earth. But for everyday intents and purposes you'd only make an extremely small error by assuming them to coincide.